# Azure Function - Send a message from an Event Hub Trigger to an Azure SignalR Service

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-eventhub, azure-signalr

I am trying to send a message to Azure SignalR Service from an Azure Function EventHub Trigger.

I don't get an exception, not even information on the output window, what am i doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace AzureFunction_EventHubToSignalR
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("dio", Connection = "EventHubSharedAccessPolicyConnectionString")] EventData[] events, 
                                     [SignalR(HubName = "%AzureSignalRHubName%")] IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages, 
                                     ILogger log)
        {
            var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

            foreach (EventData eventData in events)
            {
                try
                {
                    string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.Body.Array, eventData.Body.Offset, eventData.Body.Count);

                    await signalRMessages.AddAsync(
                       new SignalRMessage
                       {
                           Target = "BroadcastMessage",
                           Arguments = new[] { messageBody }
                       });

                    await signalRMessages.FlushAsync();

                    // Replace these two lines with your processing logic.
                    log.LogInformation($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {messageBody}");
                    await Task.Yield();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    log.LogError($"Event Hub trigger failed to process or send a message: {e}");
                    // We need to keep processing the rest of the batch - capture this exception and continue.
                    // Also, consider capturing details of the message that failed processing so it can be processed again later.
                    exceptions.Add(e);
                }
            }

            // Once processing of the batch is complete, if any messages in the batch failed processing throw an exception so that there is a record of the failure.

            if (exceptions.Count > 1)
                throw new AggregateException(exceptions);

            if (exceptions.Count == 1)
                throw exceptions.Single();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason i could not get it to work using the SignalR extensions, instead i ended up using the original SignalR packages (**Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core**) to send a message to Azure SignalR Service..

```
 [FunctionName("Function1")]
 public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("dio", Connection = "EventHubSharedAccessPolicyConnectionString")] EventData[] events,
                              [SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "%AzureSignalRHubName%")] SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo,
                              ILogger log)
 {
 ....
     //Build connection with token
     HubConnection _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
     .WithUrl(connectionInfo.Url, option =>
     {
          option.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {connectionInfo.AccessToken}");
     })
     .Build();

     //Start the hub connection
     await _connection.StartAsync();

     //My Hub has a BroadcastMessage method that receives 2 arguments
     await _connection.SendAsync("BroadcastMessage", "test", "test", default);
 ...
 }
```